# DHCP optinos set with MS DNS on VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-vpc

I set up a VPC with a private subnet that has MS AD and MS DNS server, I created a new DHCP options set and pointed to the new DNS server and disabled AWS's internal one. EC2 instances are using MS DNS server fine for resolution but the DNS is not being updated automatically with A records for newly joined instances. Can someone please point me to what the problem might be? DNS is on a 2012 R2 server which DNS updates are enabled by default.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Does your DHCP know (Properties > Advanced)  the credentials to your DNS?

Comment: I don't see where that option is available on AWS, just see an option to delete the DHCP options set or create a new one. When I was creating the options set I did not see any place where I can provide creds.

Comment: But you *have* a Windows DHCP (which is the only one that is able to update your Windows DNS Zones)?

Comment: No, I am using amazon internal DHCP service "dhcp options set". which allows you to define dns servers for the VPC.

Comment: Then you can't use the [Windows feature](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/the-enterprise-cloud/how-do-i-configure-dhcp-for-dynamic-updates-in-windows-server-2008/), that allows your DHCP to make DNS entries for its clients.

Comment: makes sense. Thank you very much for your help. One more question please. Is it possible to deploy a windows DHCP server in AWS VPC and override the DHCPOptionsset provided by Amazon? I know there is an option to turn off DHCP on VPC, just wondering if a windows DHCP server will work? Thanks again!

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I suspect it will not work. Your instances do not necessarily share the same L2 Network, so 'classic' DHCP will not work.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for your help!!